# In boto3 client.copy how do you replace the key with an updated version of the key's address?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm in the process of moving a crap-ton of files from one S3 account to another, and I'm having some problems with some of the files.

In S3 I have some file names with some weird characters at the end. Little pictures of hearts or 100! or whatever. Like this:
[image]

After looking at things way too long, I've decided that there's a problem with keys likes this. The actual Object url in S3 looks like

```
https://infoYouDoNotNeed+Resume%F0%9F%92%9B%F0%9F%92%9A%E2%9D%A4.docx
```

But if I print my copy_source, the key looks like

```
'Key': u'notNeededInfo\U0001f49b\U0001f49a\u2764.docx'
```

And when I run the script I see the following error in my terminal

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: Couldn't parse the specified URI.
```

I'm like 99% certain that it's something to do with that key, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it. I have tried using urllib, encode, decode, replace, but nothing seems to get it to an address in my s3.meta.client.copy function that will copy.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def get_versions(bucket_object_key):
    # get a list of versions for the object
    response = source_client.list_object_versions(
        Bucket=args.source,
        Prefix=bucket_object_key
    )
    # this needs to go in reverse order
    # for each version in order from first entered to most recent...
    for version in response['Versions'][::-1]:
        # get the key
        v_key = version['Key']
        # encode v_key to ignore out of bounds ascii characters
        new_key = version['Key'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        # get the versionId
        v_id = version['VersionId']
        try:
            # set the arguments for the source, filename, and version
            copy_source = {
                'Bucket': args.source,
                'Key': v_key,
                'VersionId': v_id
            }
            print copy_source
            # copy the file/version to the destination bucket
            s3.meta.client.copy(
                copy_source,
                dest_bucket,
                new_key
            )
            # Log the success
            logging.info('File %s copied, version %s' % (v_key, v_id))
            dest_object = dest_client.get_object(
                Bucket=args.dest,
                Key=new_key
            )
            new_v_id = dest_object['VersionId']
            logging.info('%s New versionId %s' % (v_key, new_v_id))
            print('copy of %s version %s successful' % (v_key, v_id))

        except ClientError as e:
            # log the failure
            logging.error('Error copying %s, version %s' % (key, v_id))
            print 'Error copying {} {}'.format(
                key.encode('ascii', 'ignore'),
                v_id
            )
            print e
```

I would love some suggestions on how to make this work, because there are a lot of psychopath applicants (I'm assuming they did this to me) that have these on their resumes. It could be the recruiters that did it, but either way someone has put those pictures on there, and I need to move those files somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the destination `Key` to:

```
Key=''.join([c for c in new_key if c in string.printable])
```

Be sure to `import string` first.

Comment: That just led to the key being stripped of the special characters, which meant that when the copy method went to find the file it sent back a 404.

Comment: I suggested to do that to the **destination** key, not the source key.